# Cursor offset on a large monitor in Windows 10

Tags: interface, customization, windows

Using Blender with a large monitor (22" or 24", I've tried both), resolution 1920x1080, scaled 100% with Windows 10, Blender adds extra height between the header bar and the menu bar. This causes the mouse position to be offset from where Blender thinks it is for the file menu and everything below, and pushes the status bar out of view at the bottom of the screen.

[image]
[image]
[image]

What's weird is that if I scale the interface in Windows 10 settings to 125%, the issue is lessened, and if I set it to 150%, the issue goes away. I can then change the resolution scale in Blender to .75, but then everything else I use on that screen looks huge.

I'm using Blender 3.5.1, but it's been the same since I started with 2.8.

I'm still pretty new to Blender; is there a setting that I'm missing? Or is this a known issue? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Looks to me like a bug in Blender combined with a "feature" in Windows.

Comment: What version of Blender? What size is the monitor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reported this as a bug, and Pratik at Blender was quick to reply, suggesting that I needed to update the graphics driver. Apparently Acer had customized the driver, so Windows would never update it. Once I downloaded an updated driver and manually installed it, the issue was resolved.

Hope this helps someone!